# Could not obtain a WAC access token

Tags: excel, api, microsoft-graph-api, wac

I am trying to access an excel worksheet from Microsoft Graph API but receiving the error:

"Could not obtain a WAC access token".

The permissions is attached in the image

[image]

and the URL I have built to try and get to the worksheets/create a session is this

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<site id>/drives/<drive id>/root:/TEMP/Book.xlsx:/workbook/createSession
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/workbook-createsession?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) you need delegated permission `Files.ReadWrite`.

Application permissions are not supported. What I know application permissions are not supported for working with excel workbooks (`/workbook/xxx` endpoints).